# Combining git GUI with the context menu?

Tags: nautilus, gui, git

I just installed git and qgit for Ubuntu and I want several features:

1. To be able to see the hidden .git folder within folders.
2. To be able to right-click a folder and say "create a repository here" (as is available through tortoise git)
3. To be able to right-click a folder and open git on that place (this can actually be done using "open with" - but I wondered if there is any other way)

This question might mix Ubuntu general questions with git.

Answer (score 2):

The program which integrates git with Nautilus is called RabbitVCS. It does integrate into Nautilus context menu.

[image: RabbitVCS]

As I remember, the version currently in Ubuntu repositories has some troubles integrating with Nautilus from Gnome 3 so you may need to search this site for suggestions.